# Combine two columns into one

Tags: php, mysql, sqlyog

How can I combine two columns into one. For example, I have one table named "posts" and other "posts_shared"

"posts" have these columns:

```
po_id
po_id_user
```

"posts_shared" have these columns:

```
ps_post_id 
ps_shared_by
```

What I need is to bring all the data from "posts" and "posts_shared" in only one column. How can i do this?

Comment: You mean combining two tables into one and displaying all those four columns?

Comment: just po_id and ps_post_id

Comment: Provide sample data and the desired result (by using [edit]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean combining `posts.po_id` `posts_shared.ps_post_id` into one column and the same with `po_id_user` and `ps_shared_by` then use `UNION` clause in your SQL query.

```
SELECT po_id, po_id_user
FROM  posts
UNION
SELECT ps_post_id, ps_shared_by
FROM  posts_shared;
```

But in order to make `UNION` possible, corresponding fields in your `posts` and `posts_shared` tables should have identical types.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I needed